# Override angular material css

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I want to override the css for mat-menu-panel of the angular material mat-list. I do not want to use :host/deep as it is deprecated. Using !important on the css also is not helping. How can I override the angular material css and write my own custom css ?

Comment: You can either switch off ViewEncapsulation, or add the CSS into styles.css,

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly what you want to override, your question is not very specific in this area.

The below example will override the mat-menu-item font color for example.

- As the below works, you will need to be more specific on what you
  are using !important with in order to diagnose the issue.

  ```
  .mat-menu-item {
    color:red !important;
  }
  ```

Comment: Depends which CSS file you add this to. If ViewEncapsulation gets added, the CSS rule will no longer be applicable

Comment: It does not depend on the css file, adding this to either the main style.css or the component css will work. As I am not making the recommendation to turn off ViewEncapsulation this is not a factor in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can access angular material properties to override in a nested way.

```
.mat-menu{
    .mat-menu-item{
    //your required css here
    }
}
```